# Getting Error IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
  ElseIf Comboroomdescrition.SelectedItem = "Exposed Glass" Then
        GroupBoxGlass.Show()
        GroupBoxRoomDetails.Visible = False
        GroupBoxWall.Visible = False
        GroupboxPartition.Visible = False
        ds = Database2DataSet4
        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("outside").Rows.Count - 1
            If combosseasoncode.SelectedValue = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("scode") Then
                txtglassnorthetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("north")
                txtglasssouthetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("south")
                txtglasseastetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("east")
                txtglasswestetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("west")
                txtglassneetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("northeast")
                txtglassseetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("southeast")
                txtglassswetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("southwest")
                txtglassnwetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalentglass").Rows(i).Item("northwest")
            Else
                Message("There is no ETD data available")
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf Comboroomdescrition.SelectedItem = "Exposed Wall and Roof" Then
        GroupBoxWall.Show()
        GroupBoxRoomDetails.Visible = False
        GroupBoxGlass.Visible = False
        GroupboxPartition.Visible = False
        ds = Database2DataSet4
        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("outside").Rows.Count - 1
            If combosseasoncode.SelectedValue = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("scode") Then
                txtwallnorthetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("north")
                txtwallsouthsetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("south")
                txtwalleastetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("east")
                txtwallwestetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("west")
                txtwallneetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("northeast")
                txtwallseetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("southeast")
                txtwallswetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("southwest")
                txtwallnwetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("northwest")
                txtwallroofetd.Text = ds.Tables("equivalent").Rows(i).Item("roof")
            Else
                Message("There is no ETD data available")
            End If
        Next
End.
```

When run the above code, the equivalentglass table was not executed and showing there is no row at 0 position, and the same code we use in equivalent table, it will be executed, In database the tables have data's.

Comment: I think the issue is the "Database2DataSet4" method. what is in there ? what is ds declared as? - also as reference i think its useful to check if you have any rows in the table first before trying to grab one.